# Perfomance of SELECT-query with branch in WHERE-clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I've a following legacy SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.get_orders_history
(
@FirstDt DATETIME2(6),
@LastDt DATETIME2(6),
@Class VARCHAR(12),
@PeriodType SMALLINT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE #BufferTable (OrderId INT)

INSERT  INTO #BufferTable
SELECT  DISTINCT
    O.OrderId
FROM
    BaseOrders O JOIN Classes C ON O.ClassId = C.ClassId
WHERE
    (O.Changed = 0) AND
    (C.ClassCode = @ClassCode) AND
    (
        (@PeriodType = 1 AND O.LastActionDateTime >= @FirstDt AND O.OrderDateTime < @LastDt) OR
        (@PeriodType = 2 AND O.OrderDateTime >= @FirstDt AND O.OrderDateTime <= @LastDt)
    )
OPTION(RECOMPILE);

SELECT  A.Column,
    C.Column,
    OB.Column1,
            ...
    OB.Column10,
    O.Column1,
            ...
    O.Column100,

FROM    BaseOrders OB
            JOIN #BufferTable IDL ON (OB.OrderId = IDL.OrderId)
            JOIN Orders O ON (O.OrderId = IDL.OrderId)
            JOIN Classes C ON (O.ClassId = C.ClassId)
ORDER BY 
        O.OrderId

DROP TABLE #BufferTable
GO
```

The parameter 'PeriodType' **is to be added now** and I doubt whether this way of make branch (condition in WHERE-clause) is efficient.

SP is rarely called but returns a lot of rows (100K+), so I think OPTION RECOMPILE for SELECT is reasonable solution in this case.

Could any of SQL experts suggest more efficient way to implement such branch?

--
**EDIT**: I will clarify that current prod version of SP has no parameter 'Period type' and WHERE is following:

```
WHERE
        (O.Changed = 0) AND
        (C.ClassCode = @ClassCode) AND
        (O.LastActionDateTime >= @FirstDt AND O.OrderDateTime < @LastDt)
```

My goal is to implement two types of date range type in current SP without or with minimal performance penalties.

Comment: Sample table and output?

Comment: Hi Adinugraha. I don't think that concrete tables structure and data matters in this case. It's only about approaches to write efficient if/else/switch branch.

Comment: OP, this is funny, but your magic buffer still ain't got no index even after "healing" `DISTINCT`. `CREATE TABLE #BufferTable (OrderId INT >>> PRIMARY KEY<<<)` may be? So actually I doubt a lot that this SP is supposed to be treated as totally optimized. It was contained of two scanning queries and will still be doing the same things after applying ANY new filters to first statement. I suggest you to have a better look at this code and start investigating actual execution plan. Again, as I commented Dean's answer - this `DISTINCT` does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: Hi Ivan. Thanks for your advices, I've reviewed all about and can confirm you are absolute right regarding suboptimal temp table structure and sense of `DISTINCT` because `OrderId` in `BaseOrders` is a primary key..

Comment: So I've rewrite SP, I threw away temp table and prefetch and now it contains single `SELECT` with PeriodType condition in `WHERE`-clause. SSMS execution plan shows that new version is 10-30% faster in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing OR from the initial insert and deleting afterwards with negation? Here is a code snippet.

```
CREATE TABLE #BufferTable (OrderId INT, LastActionDateTime datetime, OrderDateTime datetime)

INSERT  INTO #BufferTable
SELECT  DISTINCT
    o.OrderId
    , o.LastActionDateTime
    , o.OrderDateTime
FROM
    BaseOrders O JOIN Classes C ON O.ClassId = C.ClassId
WHERE
    (O.Changed = 0) AND
    (C.ClassCode = @ClassCode);

delete p
from #BufferTable p
where not
(
            (@PeriodType = 1 AND p.LastActionDateTime >= @FirstDt AND p.OrderDateTime < @LastDt) OR
            (@PeriodType = 2 AND p.OrderDateTime >= @FirstDt AND p.OrderDateTime <= @LastDt)
        )
```

Comment: Hi Dean. Thanks for advise, I'll try and compare timings.

Comment: My piece of advice - get rid of DISTINCT like that: `SELECT OrderId, ... FROM BaseOrders where changed=0 and exists(select 1 from classes where classId, classCode)`. Actually I'm not sure if `DISTINCT` is necessary right now, without code modification.